# What package adds user "ubuntu"

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

Probably dummy question, but I can't find answer myself.

What package adds "ubuntu" user?

While using Ubuntu LTS 20.04 [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu), mentioned user is not present. Which make sense, as image is supposed to be minimal. However I would like to avoid adding that user myself via `useradd`.

eg server distribution is equipped with mentioned user with `uid==1000`, so I believe there is package that is doing exactly that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some pre-made cloud images are spun to have an "Ubuntu" user.

That user is created by a [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) setting. You can see it among the examples in the documentation.

Comment: That make sense. By any chance, do you know where I can find cloud-init configuration that is used to build public ISO images created by Canonical (if it's public)?

Comment: Well, that documentation was written by Canonical folks, so I'd start by looking at https://launchpad.net/cloud-init and follow the many leads there until you find the file (or person) you need.